# Tapping into built in textarea undo/redo stack

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, undo

Textareas and editable iframes have built in undo/redo, but when inserting specific contents, those cannot be undone, since they do not appear inside the undo buffer. Is there any way to insert custom states into the undo/redo buffer or once you have done so, a total custom approach must be ued?

Comment: 12 years later and there still doesn't seem to be a native way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thee's no way to manipulate the browser's built-in undo stack. However, work is under way in WHATWG to specify an API to do this. It will be a while before it's available in browsers.